# Yii2: kartik\Select2 dropdown list in Gridview filter

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2

I want to change the inbuilt search box filter in a `Gridview` with a `Select2` button (dropdown button which allows the user to write the option manually). I use two merged tables and `wp_id` is a column in both tables, and `user_id` is a column in the `Accounts` model. With the code used here, I see on my Grid a simple text input the default one.

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'attribute' => 'wp_id',
                'value' => 'accounts.user_id',
                'filter' => $form->field($searchModel, 'wp_id')
                    ->widget(
                        Select2::className(),
                        [
                            'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Accounts::find()->all(), 'wp_id', 'user_id'),
                            'options' => ['placeholder' => ' --Filter by user id-- '],
                            'language' => 'en',
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true,
                            ],
                        ]),
            ],
        ],
]
) ?>
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: It would help to add if it's Wordpress, Wordpress plugin related.

Comment: No Wordpress used, it's written on Yii2 basic framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there isn't any `$form` here that you are trying to use, you should initialize the select2 directly using the widget and specify the `attribute` and `model` properties of the select2 widget.

See below how your code should look like.

```
<?php

    echo GridView::widget(
        [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                [
                    'attribute' => 'wp_id',
                    'value' => 'accounts.user_id',
                    'filter' => Select2::widget(
                        [
                            'model' => $searchModel,
                            'attribute' => 'wp_id',
                            'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Accounts::find()->all(), 'wp_id', 'user_id'),
                            'options' => ['placeholder' => ' --Filter by user id-- '],
                            'language' => 'en',
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ),
                ],
            ],
        ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as far as the dropdown button is concerned. But now another issue appeared - the filter doesn't filter anything, on click it only refreshes the page.

Comment: Did you implemented the filter in the search model?

Comment: No, I didn't. Which filter Interface should I implement?

Comment: @IvailoPetrov that is a separate question and you should add a new question for that, the problem in this question has been solved

Comment: Ok, I added a new question about the new problem. Thanks again for the support!